# how to get data from list use c# and Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have classes

```
public class DevicePart
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int Distance {get;set;}
}

public class Device
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public List<DevicePart> Parts {get;set;}
}

public class Data
{
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public int ParentId{get;set;}
    public int Distance{get;set;}
}
```

and I have list with Data:

- 1;Phone;0;0
- 2;TV;0;0
- 3;battery;1;5
- 4;button;1;3
- 5;webcam;2;5

how can I create optimal and faster linq query(or recursion procedure) to create object `List<Device>` from my Data list

Comment: What is a `object List`?

Comment: object list - List<Data> with 5 example row in my question

Comment: Faster than what? We need to see what you are comparing to.

Comment: Agree with Richard. Additionally you have given no indication of how you would get from a `Data` to a `Device` so its kind of hard for us to tell you how to help. Do you have a method that takes a `Data` (which is a very undescriptive class name and probably wants to be changed in some way - everything is data after all) and converts it to a `Device`, etc.

Comment: So you have also recursion, how deep can it be? Have you tried anything?

Comment: I try get Device object first(get row where ParentId = 0) and then use foreach I get DeviceParts for all Device. All work But I in my case I do two query. First time I get device, second time I get parts for new list(lit with Device only objects). And I think I need use better way to get data. To get data from DB I use very simple query db.Data.ToList()

Comment: @TimSchmelter - There's no recursion in the OP's code.

Comment: @Enigmativity: `Data` has `ParentId` which seems to be the source for the  `List<DevicePart>` in `Device`. So battery belongs to phone, but can this phone also have another parent? Maybe i'm overcomplicating this but it could be relevant for some approaches.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter no, Phone has no parent

Comment: @Std_Net: but a battery could also contain device-parts, right?

Comment: @Tim Schmelter No battery has no any parts. Data have only one deep level. Device and parts. Part can't be device

Comment: @TimSchmelter - It's a bit confusing. `Data` has `ParentId`, but it's not for recursive `Data` instances. It's just for the parent `Device` that a `DevicePart` can have. The `Data` class is just a flat overloaded data type for building `Device` and `DevicePart`. No recursion, just confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var data = new List<Data>()
{
    new Data() { Id = 1, Name = "Phone", ParentId = 0, Distance = 0 },
    new Data() { Id = 2, Name = "TV", ParentId = 0, Distance = 0 },
    new Data() { Id = 3, Name = "battery", ParentId = 1, Distance = 5 },
    new Data() { Id = 4, Name = "button", ParentId = 1, Distance = 3 },
    new Data() { Id = 5, Name = "webcam", ParentId = 2, Distance = 5 },
};

var lookup = data.ToLookup(x => x.ParentId);

var devices =
    lookup[0]
        .Select(x => new
        {
            ID = x.Id,
            x.Name,
            Parts =
                lookup[x.Id]
                    .Select(y => new
                    {
                        y.Id,
                        y.Name,
                        y.Distance,
                    })
                    .ToList(),
        })
        .ToList();
```

It gives me this:

[image: devices]

Comment: Yes, first time when I update page I see code without lookup initialization. Now I see it

Comment: @Std_Net - Sorry, I didn't copy and paste all of my code to start with. I fixed it pretty quickly. :-)